# Access a nested (grouped by) Laravel collection in Twig

Tags: laravel, collections, twig

I have a collection like this: how do I access/display the collection in twig. The original collection worked fine with the code below. Then I used I used groupby() in the collection to nest the data but now not sure how to access the data in twig.

```
Collection {#1516 ▼
#items: array:3 [▼
"Breakfast" => Collection {#1512 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => {#1491 ▼
      +"mtpid": 28
      +"mealname": "Breakfast"
      +"mealtypename": "Cold Drink"
      +"mtcode": "cbev"
      +"mealitemname": "Water"
      +"start_time": "07:00:00"
      +"end_time": "11:30:00"
      +"dateav": "2018-08-08"
    }
    1 => {#1495 ▶}
    2 => {#1497 ▶}
  ]
}
"Dinner" => Collection {#1513 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▶]
}
"Lunch" => Collection {#1514 ▼
  #items: array:9 [▶]
}
```

]
}

code example :

```
{% for meal in groupedcollection %}
{% if loop.last %}
{
title: 'test {{ meal.mealname }}',
start: '{{meal.dateav}}T{{ meal.start_time }}',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using `groupBy()`, each value in the primary collection will be another `Collection` object, which could have 0-n (or any number of zero or more) values.

Think of it like an array of arrays. You want something like this:

```
foreach ($groupedcollection as $mealname => $collectionOfMeals) ...
```

[Translated to Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#iterating-over-keys-and-values):

```
{% for mealname, items in groupedcollection %}
```

`mealname` will correspond to the keys ("Breakfast", "Dinner"), and `items` will be the collection for that key, which you can then iterate or decipher as desired.